# override phpmyadmin upload limit

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04, ispconfig

I have already increased these variable data for my server and I can see it using phpinfo()
But the problem is, phpmyadmin still showing upload limit as (Max: 2,048KiB). Running ubuntu 18, php 7.2, ispconfig3

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 128M
max_input_vars = 3000
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 1800
max_allowed_packet=500M
php_value upload_max_filesize 120M //file size
php_value post_max_size 120M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself.
php.ini under /etc/apache/ have to modify to override default value 2MB upload size for phpmyadmin.
While /etc/php/7.2/php.d/30-user.ini  can override values for php.